# Linux script to insert in a file a new line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a problem I am trying to write a script that will allowed me to write on a conf file for so i was trying to use a sed command but it looks like it works but doesn't save it in the file so my script is

```
sed '/# Load Java configuration/i JBOSS_User=root'  ITg.conf
```

this should add "JBOSS_User=root" after the line "# Load Java configuration"

How can I do it?

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't think it is a duplicate to this one. However, the solutions there may help: you need to say `sed 's/find/replace/' file` and use `-i` to perform in-place replacement.

Comment: @fedorqui I realized that in the moment I've pressed the button. Unfortunately SO doesn't allow me to change that. However, the answers there will help. Actually there are likely a ton of valid duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
sed -i '/# Load Java configuration/i JBOSS_User=root'  ITg.conf
```

before this command, make backup as below;

```
cp ITg.conf ITg.conf_backup
```

man sed :

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

              edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```